# Syntax for specifying list in csv file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to specify a list as the values of a property in csv file so that it can be loaded through load_csv as list.

Currently, I am specifying it as string and using split to add it in to list as below. Is there a better way?

```
WITH n, split(n.lab, \",\") as labels limit {limit}
call apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), labels)
```

Is there a way to avoid using split by reading it as list while doing load_csv. what's the syntax of list in csv file?

Answer (score 1):

With `LOAD CSV`, each line in a CSV file without headers is accessed as a list, so you can just leave each label as a separate item in the line and generate a new list from those items.

For example, if each line starts with a node ID and ends with 1 or more labels:

```
LOAD CSV FROM '...' AS line
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(TOINTEGER(line[0]), line[1..]);
```